# Can we implement discrete window rule in Drools?

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

I have a requirement to implement a discrete window rule to my rule Engine. My requirement is to collect 10m (time) of data and then do some action on the collected data. Help me with any approach. Do Drools support discrete windowing?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **No**. As weird as it sounds, this kind of windows are not supported out of the box by Drools. Every time I have to use a discrete window I end up creating my own rules to create, populate and process what I call "buckets" (the discrete window).

Comment: can we bucket values in Drool rules? Let say I want to 10 min event data to bucket and then do some action on that data.

Comment: yes but you can't use a sliding window to do it (or it is not really necessary at least). You will need to keep track of the time by yourself maybe using a [timer](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#_timers_and_calendars) in one of your rules.

Comment: The timer will help to execute the rule based on the time we set to the timer but how will i bucket the data? Are you saying me to bucket the data manually like a separate rule to bucket the data?

Comment: Correct. You will need some rules like: "Create a new bucket if none is open", "Add element to bucket", "Close Bucket". I'm not saying that the implementation is going to be trivial though.

Comment: I want to understand it more. As per my understanding you are saying to create a  new rule to bucket the data and that rule will only bucket the data and store to a global variable. Is this what you are saying? An example on what you are saying will help me to understand everything. Can you give an example?